# Remove Special Characters from an Oracle String

Tags: sql, regex, oracle11g

From within an Oracle 11g database, using SQL, I need to remove the following sequence of special characters from a string, i.e.

```
~!@#$%^&*()_+=\{}[]:”;’<,>./?
```

If any of these characters exist within a string, except for these two characters, which I DO NOT want removed, i.e.: `"|"` and `"-"` then I would like them completely removed.

For example:

From: `'ABC(D E+FGH?/IJK     LMN~OP'` To: `'ABCD EFGHIJK     LMNOP'` after removal of special characters.

I have tried this small test which works for this sample, i.e:

```
select regexp_replace('abc+de)fg','\+|\)') from dual
```

but is there a better means of using my sequence of special characters above without doing this string pattern of `'\+|\)'` for every special character using Oracle SQL?

Comment: Yes, you should use a character class (like this: `[!@#$%^&]` or `[^a-zA-Z]`) as using the alternation `|` will cause back tracking in the match, which slows it down.

Answer (score 10):

You can replace anything other than letters and space with empty string

```
[^a-zA-Z ]
```

here is [online demo](http://regex101.com/r/aB5pO6/1)

---

As per below comments

> I still need to keep the following two special characters within my string, i.e. "|" and "-".

Just exclude more

```
[^a-zA-Z|-]
```

**Note:** hyphen `-` should be in the starting or ending or escaped like `\-` because it has special meaning in the Character class to define a range.

For more info read about [Character Classes or Character Sets](http://www.regular-expressions.info/charclass.html)

Comment: Thanks but apart from my special character list, I still need to keep the following two special characters within my string, i.e. "|" and "-".

Comment: Just include it in the character class. `[^a-zA-Z|-]`

Answer (score 0):

Consider using this regex replacement instead:

```
REGEXP_REPLACE('abc+de)fg', '[~!@#$%^&*()_+=\\{}[\]:”;’<,>.\/?]', '')
```

The replacement will match any character from your list.

Here is a [regex demo](http://regex101.com/r/hR4oR8/2)!

Comment: Pls see updated question - need to keep "|" and "-" in string if it exists.

Comment: FYI, just ran your query in Oracle 11g, i.e. select regexp_replace('abc+de)fg','[~!@#$%^&*()_+=\\{}[\]:”;’<,>.\/?]') a from dual and unfortunately did not remove any of those specials characters. Need it to work in Oracle 11g SQL. Thanks.

Comment: @tonsils I completed the replacement with the third argument.

Comment: Really appreciate your help but I went into SQL Fiddle, selected Oracle 11gR2 for DB, built schema and then added this sql statement select REGEXP_REPLACE('abc+de)fg', '[~!@#$%^&*()_+=\\{}[\]:”;’<,>.\/?]', '') a
from dual and still did not remove any of the special characters.

Comment: @tonsils I read some SQL docs. It seems that the syntax of regexp in SQL does not support escaping. Therefore [this](http://sqlfiddle.com/#!4/d41d8/34003) should be the final approach, as `\]` within `[]` is considered to close the group.

Answer (score 0):

The regex to match your sequence of special characters is:

```
[]~!@#$%^&*()_+=\{}[:”;’<,>./?]+
```

Answer (score 0):

I feel you still missed to escape all regex-special characters.
To achieve that, go iteratively:
build a test-tring and start to build up your regex-string character by character to see if it removes what you expect to be removed.
If the latest character does not work you have to escape it.
That should do the trick.

Answer (score 0):

```
SELECT TRANSLATE('~!@#$%sdv^&*()_+=\dsv{}[]:”;’<,>dsvsdd./?', '~!@#$%^&*()_+=\{}[]:”;’<,>./?',' ')
FROM dual;
```

result:

```
TRANSLATE
-------------
 sdvdsvdsvsdd
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use this:

```sql
regexp_replace('ABC(D E+FGH?/IJK     LMN~OP','\W')
```

This type of input in `regexp_replace` function, will easily revised by `\W` value.
Also, the input value of `\w` can keep special chars and remove (or replace) all alphabetical chars.

Answer (score -1):

```
SQL> select translate('abc+de@fg-hq!m', 'a+-@!', etc.) from dual;

TRANSLATE(
----------
abcdefghqm
```